# It is recommended by google to use reflection in Android?

Tags: android, reflection

I know that if you search in google you can find posts from android developers using reflection, but these posts are from 2009, 2010... etc

I remember that i read some time ago in a post in stackoverflow a guy that linked some posts from official android developers telling that reflection is not a good practice in android.

I can't find any official android(google) info about if it is a good practice or not.

Somneone have's an official link? (not from 2009)

thanks

Answer (score -1):

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#DependencyInjection

see **Avoid dependency injection frameworks** paragraph

Comment: Reflection = dependency injection?

Comment: I pick up this doc because Guice uses reflection quite heavily so it somehow implies that reflection is not good for perf.